# Push notification server issue

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

I am using `Apns` for sending push notification , it is working with my `dev server`.
Here is the url

http://website-center.co.il/projects/mobileapps/test1.php

And here is the another server on which same script is applied.

http://www.amigos-groups.com/mobileapps/test1.php

For it I am getting error

```
Failed to connect: 111 Connection refused.
```

Comment: yes it got resolved. actually its related with the server

Comment: I also fixed it. Port 2195 was not open on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Is your certificate set correctly on the other site?  Post some code.

More information is needed in order to help you solve your problem.  Please add your PHP code that is in question to your question.  Thanks.

Comment: I didn't realize how to make a comment. Sorry.

Comment: @DarknessBeginsHere user does not have enough rep to post comments yet. so this is perfectly acceptable. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment)

Answer (score 0):

Push certificates for production and development are different. And to make more difficult device tokens for production and sandbox are different for the same device. Cross check if these are correct and Im sure you must have faltered in this.